# Tkinter scrollbars let user scroll more than they should

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, scrollbar

I'm developing a "cell" matrix using python 3.6 and tkinter, I've modified a scrolled frame class (code below) because scrollbars let me scroll though there isn't space left in the scrollbar. The result is an undesired space (see images below) . I used the class AutoScrollbar to gray out the scrollbar when it's not needed and worked fine under Windows, but under Linux still let me scroll further than it should and doesn't gray out.

- is there any way to prevent tkinter scrollbars to allow scroll further then they should?

**Under Windows:** [image: Grays out]
**Under Linux:** [image: Not grayed out but still let me scroll]

```
import tkinter as tk   
from tkinter import ttk

class AutoScrollbar(tk.Scrollbar):
    def set(self, lo, hi):
        if float(lo) <= 0.0 and float(hi) >= 1.0:
            tk.Scrollbar.set(self, 0.0, 1.0)
        else:
            tk.Scrollbar.set(self, lo, hi)

class ScrolledFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kw):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kw)            
        vscrollbar = AutoScrollbar(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        vscrollbar.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.RIGHT, expand=False)
        hscrollbar = AutoScrollbar(self, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
        hscrollbar.pack(fill=tk.X, side=tk.BOTTOM, expand=False)       
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0,
                            yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set,
                            xscrollcommand=hscrollbar.set,
                            bg ='gray')
        canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        vscrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
        hscrollbar.config(command=canvas.xview)
        # reset the view
        canvas.xview_moveto(0)
        canvas.yview_moveto(0)
        # create a frame inside the canvas which will be scrolled with it
        self.interior = interior = tk.Frame(canvas)
        interior_id = canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=interior,
                                           anchor=tk.NW)
        # detect changes on interior size
        def _configure_interior(event):
            # adjust size of scroll region
            size = (interior.winfo_reqwidth(), interior.winfo_reqheight())
            #print('size interior = canvas: '+str(size))
            canvas.config(scrollregion="0 0 %s %s" % size)
        interior.bind('<Configure>', _configure_interior)
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that you are setting the `scrollregion` at the appropriate time and with the appropriate values?

Comment: I tried to force the gray out by using  the "Autoscrollbar" class instead of the standard tk.Scrollbar but didn't work.